# Is there a way to restore all terminals at startup

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, restore

I would like to know if there is a way to restore all terminals after a reboot?

The following thread refers to 'System > Preferences > Session'
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=791504

Which I understand is now 'System > Preferences > Startup Applications' for Ubuntu 10.04+

In, Startup Application, if 'Automatically remember running applications when logging out' is checked, the terminals are restored with the correct directory.

But the 'title' set for each terminal resets to 'Terminal'. 
Is there a way to restore the 'title' attribute too?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this using screen.

I just have one terminal autostart using screen on my server. When I walk over to it i can see all the status messages already scrolling through. You can name each window too. Put the following block of text in the .screenrc file in your home directory. When you start screen it executes.

[This page has .screenrc examples](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/Screen/screenrc_examples.shtml), including this one:

```
hardstatus string '%{= kg}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{= kw}%?%-Lw%?%{=b kR}(%{W}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{=b kR})%{= kw}%?% Lw%?%?%= %{g}]%{=b C}[ %d %M %c ]%{W}

screen -t rOOt 0 su -
screen -t ncmpc 1 bash
screen -t terminal 2 bash
screen -t MComander 3 mc
screen -t vimTerm 4 bash
screen -t terminal 5 bash
screen -t dropbox 6 bash
```

The hardstatus line gives your command windows at the bottom of the terminal, and each line below that defines the startup program.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also save your terminals to disk - which means they will be able to survive a restart.

Comment: Thank you @Teque5. Worked perfectly. Sorry for the delay.
MarcoCeppi, I don't exactly know how to do that now, but I'll find it and let you know. Thank you.